# underscores are converted into hypens in rails headers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, header

Hi I have restful apis in rails and react-redux at front-end..

**At front-end:**

```
axios.defaults.headers.access_token = "default values"
axios.defaults.headers.some_header_token = "some value"
```

i.e I have sent two parameters from client-side

1. `access_token`
2. `some_header_token`

**What I'm Getting at rails server**

At my console I'm getting

```
 request.header["access_token"] = nil
 request.header["some_header_token"] = nil
```

but getting values in

```
request.header["access-token"]
request.header["some-header-token"]
```

**underscores** are getting converted into **hypens**

Comment: question is not clear can you post some code here.

Comment: @satendra: I have updated my question

Answer (score 3):

[Ref](https://github.com/tawan/rails/blob/349f187f58491f2c2ef929ec0b46d78d4e888e85/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/headers.rb#L2)

```
# Provides access to the request's HTTP headers from the environment.
#
env     = { "CONTENT_TYPE" => "text/plain", "HTTP_USER_AGENT" => "curl/7.43.0" }
headers = ActionDispatch::Http::Headers.new(env)
headers["Content-Type"] # => "text/plain"
headers["User-Agent"] # => "curl/7/43/0"
```

Also note that when headers are mapped to CGI-like variables by the Rack
server, both dashes and underscores are converted to underscores. This
ambiguity cannot be resolved at this stage anymore. Both underscores and
dashes have to be interpreted as if they were originally sent as dashes.

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
#    ...
User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
X_Custom_Header: token
#
headers["X_Custom_Header"] # => nil
headers["X-Custom-Header"] # => "token"
```

Even though underscores in header names
are rarely encountered, they are valid according to RFC822 [1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2).

Comment: Another interesting thing. Header values are concatenated if two header names only differing in underscore and dash are sent.